# Parallel Tempering and Bayesian Non-Parametrics

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, dirichlet-process, parallel-tempering

In parallel tempering, we run multiple MCMC chains in an ascending temperature ladder, where the posterior density of the $i$th chain is exponentiated to the reciprocal of the temperature of the $i$th chain.

$$
f(x,\theta\mid T_i) := f(x,\theta)^{\frac{1}{T_i}}
$$

Then chain states are swapped at intervals with probability

$$
\alpha_{1,2} = \min\left[ 1, \exp\lbrace (T_2^{-1} - T_1^{-1}) \times (E_2 - E_1)\rbrace\right]
$$

Where $E_t$ is the "energy", or log-posterior-density, of the distribution for chain $t$.

Consider a stick-breaking representation of the infinite mixture model.  Then

$$
f(x\mid\pi,\theta) = \sum_{j = 1}^J\pi_j f_0(x\mid\theta_j).
$$

Obviously truncating the mixture at $J$.  Under the stick-breaking model, $\pi = S(\nu)$, the stick-breaking function. Whether it's Dirichlet process or GEM, say the prior for $\nu$ is $f(\nu)$.  Finally, the cluster parameters have their centering distribution and associated hyperpriors, $f(\theta)$.  So the posterior is proportional to

$$
f(y,\theta) \propto \sum_{j = 1}^J \pi_j f_0(y\mid\theta) \times f(\nu) \times f(\theta)
$$

Finally, say I want to do parallel tempering on this model.  Is $f(y,\theta)$ as described here the quantity I exponentiate to the reciprocal of the temperature?  Does that not induce a lot of noise, as I include information for clusters with no data?